# How to pass context or update SwiftData in ViewModel

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftData object called `UserLocation` that I want to update with a new item anytime a button is clicked that gets the users current location. I have a `ViewModel` that currently gets the location and adds it to an array but I can't figure out how to pass the `ModelContext` to my `ViewModel` to update. Or is there a way to track the changes in my `@Published` variable in the view to update the `ModelContext`?

```
import SwiftData
import MapKit

struct LocationTestView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var userLocations: [UserLocation]
    @StateObject private var viewModel = LocationTestViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            List {
                ForEach(userLocations) { userLocation in
                  //add view data
                }
            }
            Button(action: addUserLocation, label: {
                Text("Get Location")
            })
        }
    }
    
    private func addUserLocation() {
        withAnimation {
            viewModel.getCurrentLocation()
        }
    }
}

final class LocationTestViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    @Published var coordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }
    
    func getCurrentLocation() {
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let latestLocation = locations.first else {
            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.coordinates.append(latestLocation.coordinate); //Need to update userLocations instead
        }
        
        print(coordinates)
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: any Error) {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Add it as a parameter to getCurrentLocation() and pass it from the view whenever that function is called. (Or drop the view model and handle everything in the view but that is a completely different route)

Comment: Make the container a static property so you can call it in the View and somewhere else

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I did try to drop the view model but then I was stuck on how to assign the CLLocationManagerDelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SwiftUI the `View` struct hierarchy is the view model already shouldn't try to put view data into state objects, those are designed for model or fetched data where you need reference semantics (like delegation in your case). This is because the `View` struct hierarchy is designed to efficiently track changes to your model/fetched data and call `body` to make new structs (which are then diffed by SwiftUI to create/update the actual UI objects). The `View` structs are lightweight, descriptor type values on the memory stack, there is no issue with making lots of them quickly, same way you wouldn't care about making multiple ints. Structs for view data are more efficient and less likely to have consistency mistakes compared with view model objects.

I recommend renaming your `LocationTestViewModel` to `LocationFetcher` and make its only job to retrieve a location. Then in your `View` struct use that location to update your SwiftData code using the context from the environment. You can put the logic for this in your SwiftData model class or in an extension on the container to make it testable.

Note, you will also need a `LocationAuthorizer` state object in a parent `AuthorizationView` that asks for authorization and thus only show this `LocationTestView` when authorized and hide it again when de-authorized.